# Étymologie de halte-garderie

Tags: étymologie, enfants

Une halte-garderie (tout au moins à Bruxelles et d'après Wikipedia, en France aussi) est une garderie à temps partiel.  Je me rends compte que je ne comprends pas ce nom.

Quel est son étymologie ? Quel est le sens de « halte » dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faire une *halte*, lors d'une marche par exemple, c'est s'arrêter, marquer une arrêt temporaire plus ou moins prolongé dans l'activité.

Faire une *halte* dans une ville pour une nuit et reprendre sa route le lendemain.

Durant la journée, les enfants font donc une *halte* d'une ou plusieurs heures dans un jardin d'enfant, une crèche ou une garderie pour repartir ensuite avec leurs parents.

Comment: Très bonne explication!  et évidente *a postiori*, comme toutes les bonnes explications.  Merci.